# python email new line

Tags: python, email, newline

I tried to send an email which present stocks data and send it by email,
it goes to Yahoo and take the stock price and compare to a target and present it with `%` from the target
unfortunately it all came without a space between the stocks 
I tried `\n` and `\r\n` but without success 
this is the code which I tried to wrote,

```
import smtplib
import sys
import os
import re
import bs4
import requests
import pprint
import math #ciel for round

# list of data 
stock={'MMM':145,'WM':95,'JNJ':130,'KMB':123,'PEP':117}


def get_stock(st):
    b=None
    lc=[]

    ab=re.sub(r'GNC', st, "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GNC?p=GNC&.tsrc=fin-srch")


    res=requests.get(ab)
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    b=soup.find('div',{'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}).find('span').text
    c=soup.find('h1').text

    pprint.pprint(f'for company {c} in symbol {st} the price is {b} target {stock[st]} {(float(b)/float(stock[st])-1)*100:.2f}% from target\n')
    #message='for company'+c+"in symbol"+st+' '+" the price is"+b

    message1='For company'+' '+c+' '+'in symbol'+' '+st+' '+'the price is'+' '+str(b)+' '+'target'+' '+str(stock[st])+" "+str(math.ceil((float(b)/float(stock[st])-1)*100))+'% '+'from target'+'\r\r\n'
    message1=message1+os.linesep
    lc=message1

    return message1

for symbol,price in stock.items():

    i=get_stock(symbol)




import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText



def send_email(body,user="myemail", pwd="mypassword", recipient="xxxx", subject="Reprort from Python"):

    ld=[]
    for symbol,price in stock.items():
        i=get_stock(symbol)
        ld.append(i)

        body=ld

    # Prepare actual message

    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (user, ", ".join(recipient), subject, body)

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pwd)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        print ('successfully sent the mail')
    except:
        print ("failed to send mail")

send_email(body=lc)
```

Comment: If the input is a single long line then `email` is just sending what you told it to send. More generally, you are more likely to receive useful help if you can reduce this to a [mre]. In particular, scraping a dynamic site might not produce the same result every time. Can you replace that part with a simple static string which exhibits the behavior you are trying to troubleshoot? Similarly, showing the resulting message source and explaining why it's problematic will allow us to repro without having to send email at all.

Comment: (... and perhaps reveal - or, ideally, exclude the possibility - that the root problem here is that you have unwarranted assumptions about how email works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with html formatting:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message['subject'] = 'my subject'
message['from'] = 'from'
lb = ""
for symbol,price in stock.items():
    lb += """<p>
    {0}
    </p>""".format(get_stock(symbol))
body = """<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {0}
  </body>
</html>
""".format(lb)

message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login("yourmail96@gmail.com", "yourpasssword")
    server.sendmail("asdasd", "jesus_acosta1996@hotmail.com", message.as_string())
    server.close()
except Exception:
    print("failed")
```

You can cusotmize the output the way you need with html.

Let me know if it works

Comment: The MIMEText class is suitabde for crea ing an individual body part. It's not intended to be used to create a top-level message; and certainly not by passing in an already (poorly) formatted message.

Comment: thank you any suggestion for better format ?  this is the output  ['For company MMM - 3M Company in symbol MMM the price is 167.41 target 145 16% from target\r\r\n\r\n', 'For company WM - Waste Management, Inc. in symbol WM the price is 112.20 target 95 19% from target\r\r\n\r\n'

Comment: I just changed my answer, maybe you need a html approach

Comment: Carlos, your solution was great and help me a lot  where can I learn to use Html  in a way that you used it in your script -can you recommend on online course or post '/

Comment: Hello! you just need practice, I like courses from this guy https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-developer-zero-to-mastery/ he has really nice Python courses as well, and this is awesome if you're seaching a job https://www.udemy.com/course/master-the-coding-interview-data-structures-algorithms/